# Range variable name cannot match the name of a member of the 'Object' class. when querying a DataGridView using Linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to Query a DataGridViewRowsCollection object using LINQ so I don't need a for loop. I want to get the first cells out what is a String and put it in a generic list.

Based on my knowledge and research the query should be the following:

```
Dim Result As List(Of String) = (From row In gridMappingClasses.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)()
                                 Select row.Cells(0).Value.ToString).ToList()
```

but it fails with the following error: Range variable name cannot match the name of a member of the 'Object' class.

But if I remove the ToString method call and change Result to List(of object) it works fine. Btw I am using Strict on.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Try using something else other than `row` in `From row In gridM...`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try giving it an alias (ToString is already a member of Object, can't have another one):

```
(From row In gridMappingClasses.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)()
 Select v = row.Cells(0).Value.ToString).toList
```

But there is nothing wrong with having a for loop. You should generally use LINQ for simple queries that don't cause any debugging headache. If a LINQ query starts to become problematic, it's time to rewrite it as a loop. In your case it would have resolved the problem.